# How to Write an Readable and Understandable Bitwise Operator Formula?

Tags: c++11, codeblocks

I am Learning the bitwise operator from a course downloaded from udemy but It is very confusing.
They teach by this example which is very confusing to read and understand, is there a course or example which will teach bitwise operator in simple way? and also what is the use of bitwise operator? is it important to take headache from it or not?

The example:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    main()
    {

                /*
                Operator    Symbol  Form    Operation
    left shift  <<  x << y  all bits in x shifted left y bits
    right shift >>  x >> y  all bits in x shifted right y bits
    bitwise NOT ~   ~x  all bits in x flipped
    bitwise AND &   x & y   each bit in x AND each bit in y
    bitwise OR  |   x | y   each bit in x OR each bit in y
    bitwise XOR ^   x ^ y   each bit in x XOR each bit in y


                    0
                    1
                    0101 0110
                    for example 126
                    1 * 10 ^ 2 + 2 * 10 ^ 1 + 6 * 10 ^ 0 = ?
                    1 * 10 ^ 2 = 100
                    2 * 10 ^ 1 = 20
                    6 * 10 ^ 0 = 6  why? because write 10 about 0 times = 0
                    we have the answer 126
                    1 2 6
                    3 2 1 // this is the position of 126. it's in -1 formula we can use

                    3-1=2
                    2-1=1
                    1-1=0

                    1 2 6 = 1 * 10    ^ 2    + 2 * 10    ^ 1    + 6 * 10   ^ 0
                    1 0 1 0 = 1 * 2 + 0 * 2 + 1 * 2 + 0 * 2
                    1 0 1 0 = 1 * 2 ^ 3   +   0 * 2 ^ 2   +   1 * 2 ^ 1   +   0 * 2 ^ 0   =   10
                    1 * 2 ^ 3 = 8
                    0 * 2 ^ 2 = 0
                    1 * 2 ^ 1 = 2
                    0 * 2 ^ 0 = 0
                    8 + 0 + 2 + 0 = 10
                    // Decimal notation for 1 0 1 0 is 10
                    1 0 1 1 0 0 = 0*0^0 + 0*0^1 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^3 + 0*0^4 + 1*2^5 = 44
                    0*0^0 = 0
                    0*0^1 = 0
                    1*2^2 = 4
                    1*2^3 = 8
                    0*0^4 = 0
                    1*2^5 = 32
                    0+0+4+8+0+32 = 44
                */
                cout << (10 >> 1) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: You're confusing `^` with an exponent -- it's not, it's the bitwise exclusive or. Bitwise operations are way clearer when you write the literals as hexadecimal (`0x1234`) or binary (`0b1010`), as base 10 does not align with binary.

Comment: @Quentin Ok thank you for the clear answer it really solved my confusion.